# django restframework token Authentication fail with "invalid token"

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a problem with token authentication.
I run my django app with django built in server.

```
$python manage.py runserver
```

My App's urls.py

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from .views import LectureCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/user_auth/$', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/lecture/create/$', LectureCreateView.as_view()),
]
```

My App's models.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class LectureStartView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        ...
```

and settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...

    # Rest framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',


    'myApp',
]
...


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # other settings...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

I want auth with token.
I successfully issued token.

POST '...api/user_auth/' {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "blahbalh123"
}

```
{
      "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjIwMTMyMzA2Iiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MDk5NzA5NjcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoiaW50ZXJydXBpbmdAbmF2ZXIuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA5OTcxNTY3fQ.acwqAP4sBPZWYPC0GfgL3AZarNz4Opb_5P4RewZJYrI"
}
```

but I fail Auth with Token

Request:

```
POST ...api/lecture/create/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Authorization: Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjIwMTMyMzA2Iiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MDk5NzA5NjcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoiaW50ZXJydXBpbmdAbmF2ZXIuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA5OTcxNTY3fQ.acwqAP4sBPZWYPC0GfgL3AZarNz4Opb_5P4RewZJYrI
```

Response:

```
Status: 401 Unauthorized

Allow →GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length →27
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Mon, 06 Nov 2017 12:59:17 GMT
Server →WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.13
Vary →Accept
WWW-Authenticate →Token
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN

{
    "detail": "Invalid token." 
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
sorry for my english skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing the Tokens from django-rest-framework and REST framework JWT.

In the DJR documentations says:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

You should replace your code with:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from .views import LectureCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/user_auth/$', views.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^api/lecture/create/$', LectureCreateView.as_view()),
]
```

I hope it can help you.